# Autofac ILiftetimeScope.ResolveKeyed in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, moq, autofac

I recently started using Autofac after years of working with Unity, so I'm running into some (newbie?) problems now and then.. 
Right now I have the following situation: a Factory class that uses `ILifetimeScope.ResolveKeyed` to return a specific repository, eg:

```
scope.ResolveKeyed<IDocumentRepository>(EncryptionLevel.None, new NamedParameter("container", "test"))
```

In my unit test (using AutoFac.Extras.AutoMock) I have:

```
using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
{
    mock.Mock<IDocumentRepository>().Setup(m => m.GetByIdAsync(It.IsAny<Guid>())).Returns(Task.FromResult("hello"));
}
```

The problem occurs in a unit test, it says

> The requested service 'None (Blob.IDocumentRepository)' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

I tried to mock the `ILifetimeScope` and let it return my mocked `IDocumentRepository`, but apparently that is [not possible](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extras.Moq/issues/8).

So what can I do to make the `ILifetimeScope` resolve my mocked `IDocumentRepository`?

Comment: Using `ILifetimeScope` directly could be considered as some kind of service locator antipattern, but sometimes (rarely) is needed. Are you sure you have to use it? Maybe you could inject `IIndex<K,V>` instead (see [here](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html#resolving-with-an-index))? It would be mocked quite easily...

Comment: @tdragon I tried IIndex, but I also need to provide some constructor arguments (added that to the question now). Is this also possible to achieve?

Comment: Does all of your `IDocumentRepository` implementations require this custom parameter, or just one registered with key `EncryptionLevel.None`?

Comment: There's a whole bunch of repositories that will have the same key, but use different location for storage (the 'container' parameter'), so I need a way to provide that information to the repository

Comment: If all your repostories requires `string container` parameter, you can inject `IIndex<EncryptionLevel, Func<string, IDocumentRepository>> iindex` and then create new repostories with `iindex[EncryptionLevel.None]("name")`

Comment: I finally came up with another solution, at some point I found that (part of) the problem was that my factory was a concrete class, which is not supported by AutoMock, so I created an interface for it. And instead of mocking ILifetimeManager, I mock the properties that are returning the repositories (eg. mock.Mock<IDocumentRepositoryFactory>().SetupGet(m => m.FooDocumentRepository).Returns(blobMock.Object);

Comment: Good to see you found the solution for your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You can register `Mock<T>` as `Keyed` into AutoMock factory

```
var mockToReg = new Mock<IDocumentRepository>();

using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose(builder => 
{
    b.RegisterMock(mockToReg ).Keyed<IDocumentRepository>(EncryptionLevel.None);
}))
```